# Minable crypto contract

Tags: ether

How can I create mineable cryptocurrency using ERC20 token? Do I need to code it using smart contact or need to do something else.

Also I want my personal node where will be running my Ethereum node for mining?

Answer (score 2):

There is one ERC20 token named [0xBitcoin](https://0xbitcoin.org/). Which is analogous to BTC operates within the Ethereum network. It is pure PoW mined. 0xBitcoin smart contract has an automatic difficulty adjustment mechanism. When hashrate increases, the tokens become harder to mint.

You need to check smart contract code of 0xBitcoin Token(0xBTC) : https://etherscan.io/address/0xb6ed7644c69416d67b522e20bc294a9a9b405b31#contracts

Also, this article will be very helpful to you, which explains in detail how ERC20 token mining work in 0xBitcoin: [How does ERC20 Token Mining Work?](https://medium.com/@admazzola/how-does-erc20-token-mining-work-fc91f11019f6)